# How can I modify this statement in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I modify the following statement to remove the hard-coded values $1.00 and $2.00 from the code and place them in a table of constants?

The table `sec0306_price_constants` is already set up. The `min_price` field contains 1.00 and the `max_price` field contains 2.00.

```
  SELECT description
    FROM l_foods
   WHERE price BETWEEN 1.00 AND 2.00
ORDER BY description
```

Can you explain to me the approach to doing so?

This is for Oracle.

Comment: Any particular database?  Details on the table of constants?

Comment: A permanent table of constants or a virtual one used by just that query? What RDBMS?

Comment: What other constants will go into the table of constants?

Comment: Does `sec0303_price_constants` have just one row, or many? If many, how does it relate to `l_foods`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  For SQL-related questions, it is helpful to give outline schema information, especially joining columns (foreign keys, primary keys) of the tables under discussion.  In this question, Ken White's question is also crucial: how are the rows in the price constants table related to the foods table, or is there just one row.  (To your credit, you did include the table names; it is surprising (and irritating) how often people omit table names from their questions!)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT description
FROM l_foods
WHERE (price >= (select min_price from sec0306_price_constants )
AND price <= (select max_price from sec0306_price_constants ))
ORDER BY description
```

Comment: I don't see any info on how to join the tables, so your query works only if there's a single row in the `sec0306_price_constants` table, which I doubt because `constants` is plural. You should probably wait until the question has more information before trying to answer it.

Comment: @KenWhite - Might be assuming the [Joe Celko approach](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/15628/3690)

Comment: Maybe so, but this is actually quite a common selection in the retail sector where say gift vouchers have certain denominations. It is expedient to place goods within a certain price bracket to increase sales.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Might be, might not; that's why my suggestion to wait until it was clarified. :-) Notice I did not downvote, BTW.

Comment: This is good if there's a single row in the price constants table.  If there are multiple rows, it won't work, but the fix is likely to be a minor variant on this theme (an aggregate in the sub-selects, or a WHERE condition).

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @constants table (typ varchar(10), minprice float, maxprice float)

insert into @constants values 
('dirtcheap', 0.00, 0.99),
('justright', 1.00, 2.00),
('expensive', 2.01, 10.00)

select description
from   l_foods f, @constants c
where  f.price >= c.minprice and f.price <= c.maxprice
  and  c.typ = 'justright'
```

You can qualify by different types of price ranges without changing the low and high values in the query -- just change constant type.

Comment: Please read the question. The poster says there is already a table for the constants, so there's no need to create and insert. There's just no information about how the tables should be joined yet.

Comment: True -- but the OP didn't include that in the first 3 versions of the question.

Comment: This is not valid Oracle SQL.

Comment: It was there 6 minutes before your answer was posted. :-) That's the reason I made the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry read the extra information, if you have the table setup I would structure things along these lines:

```
--BEGIN PROC

DECLARE @MINPRICE DECIMAL;
DECLARE @MAXPRICE DECIMAL;

SELECT
    @MINPRICE = min_price,
    @MAXPRICE = max_price
FROM
    sec0306_price_constants;

SELECT description
    FROM l_foods
WHERE 
    price BETWEEN @MINPRICE AND @MAXPRICE
ORDER BY description
```

Comment: The poster mentioned having a table of constants in the edit; it just doesn't indicate how to join them together. You should probably wait until more information is provided before trying to answer.

Comment: If they're constants, the join could well be optional, assuming no join the answer above should sort things.

Comment: This is not valid Oracle SQL.

Comment: If there's more than one row inthe constants table (which isn't clear at this point), it won't work. Thus my suggestion to wait for clarification. :-)

Comment: The Oracle SQL tag was added after the answer was posted...will teach me for trying to be quick!

Comment: @KenWhite Yeah, you're right, one might assume the question would include the relevant information to answer, plus appropriate tags from the get-go, else be flagged, but I'm not being pedantic!

Comment: @dougajmcdonald: OK, to be pedantic should I downvote it for being wrong? (It can't be right before we know if a JOIN is needed or not.)

Comment: @KenWhite tricky to determine, do you downvote for being right given the information? or downvote on the assumption that the question is incomplete and the potential question might include information making the answer invalid?

Comment: @dougajmcdonald: (To be clear, I am NOT downvoting this answer.) If I were to downvote, however, it would be because it can't be considered correct *until the point* the missing info about the constants table is provided (or your answer covers both cases). I'm not that mean, though. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite I know, I'm just messing about, surely we can only provide an answer based on the information provided though.

Comment: @dougajmcdonald: Or just comment on the original post and not answer at all until it's clarified (which improves the quality of the questions and makes them more meaningful for future readers)? Waiting for missing information also encourages the asker to post more complete questions in the future.

Comment: Girls!  Girls!  You're both pretty!  <sheesh!>

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT Description, price, min_price, max_price

FROM l_foods,sec0306_price_constants

WHERE (price >= (sec0306_price_constants.min_price ) AND price <= (sec0306_price_constants.max_price ))

ORDER BY description;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. OP wrote "Can you **explain** to me the approach to doing so?" in the question.